# VMWare Player crashes after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware-player

I have been using VMWare Player to run Windows XP and all went well until I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 (from 12.04). Now every time I start the vmplayer, win xp boots well, but after about a minute in the virtual machine freezes while outputting the following error:

```
*** Error in `/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx': malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x0000000001b5d300 ***
Unexpected signal: 6.
```

VMPlayer version 6.0.2 build-1744117

Host OS version 3.13.0-24-generic

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMWare player, the prior version, is wonky in 14.04. I would purge it and then install the newest version; https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation/10_0

Comment: Your link is VMware Workstation, not Player.

Comment: @bfrgzju it includes the player as part of the install.

Comment: @user178322 The latest player vmware offers is 6.02, which is the version I have at the moment.

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0

Comment: @PeterRaeves Not sure what to tell you other than I was having a similar issue after upgrading to 14.04 and it was resolved by uninstalling the standalone player and installing the workstation. It can't hurt to give it a try since your virtual machines won't be affected. Hopefully you find a resolution.

Comment: @user178322 How do I purge the player without losing my virtual machines?

Comment: @PeterRaeves sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player should sort you out. Your virtual machines are stored in a folder in your home folder and aren't uninstalled when uninstalling the VMWare player.

Comment: @user178322 Thanks. Strange, but reinstalling the player through the vm workstation's installer worked. It hasn't crashed yet. I do get warnings though. Were you able to solve these warnings?

Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Comment: @PeterRaeves it appears that the module isn't where the system expects it to be. Try reinstalling; sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module or sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module:i386